# Erro ao tentar fazer update na tabela usando C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

Criei um formulário para alterar uma tabela, porém o meu update não está funcionando.

```
    cnxCli.sel =/*"set dateformat dmy \n"+ */
                "update Cliente" +
                 "set Nome = '" + txtNome.Text +"'," +
                 "Rg = '" + mskRg.Text + "'," +
                 "Cpf ='" + mskCpf.Text + "'," +
                 "Celular ='" + mskCelular + "'," +
                 "Telefone ='" + mskTelefone + "'," +
                 "DataNascimento = '" + mskNascimento.Text + "'," +
                 "Endereco ='" + txtEndereco.Text + "'," +
                 "Bairro='" + txtBairro.Text + "'," +
                 "Cidade='" + "'," +
                 "Cep ='" + mskCep.Text + "'," +
                 "Observacao='" + txtObs.Text + "'" +
                 "where IDCliente =" + IdCliSel;
    cnxCli.selCmd.CommandText = cnxCli.sel;
    bool deuErro = false;
    try
    {
        cnxCli.selCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        deuErro = true;
        //throw;
    }
    if (!deuErro)
        MessageBox.Show("Cadastro do cliente " + IdCliSel + " atualizado com sucesso!");
```

A exceção lançada: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - Incorrect syntax near 'Nome'`.

Para mim a sintaxe parece correta, tanto é que copiei o código direto do SQL Server 2014, onde tinha acabado de executar o comando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe um erro de sintaxe porque falta um espaço em `"update Cliente" +`, desta forma juntou tudo.

Mas este é um problema até menor, o código todo tem vários problemas.

Nunca monte uma *query* dessa forma, é inseguro e desorganizado. Veja na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters) o jeito correto de fazer.

Ainda pode haver vazamento de memória.

Mesmo fazendo desse jeito errado ainda poderia ser simplificado, e coisas mais simples dão menos erros e quando eles acontecem, são mais fáceis de serem achados.

A forma de captura de exceção está bem errada. Eu ensino em [diversas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D).

Todas as colunas são `varchar`? É improvável. Vai dar outros erros corrigindo este.

Tem outros pequenos problemas e algo indica que o resto do código está ruim também. Assim vai acumulando problemas e vai cansando e achando que o problema está na linguagem de programação. Tem que aprender como faz, tem que ser algo estruturado, não adianta seguir receitas de bolo.

Comment: Concordo com tudo o que você disse. O código vem dando vários problemas.

Mas esse ainda é meu primeiro sistema. Além disso, estou usando os minutos que sobram no trabalho ou depois da janta para programar. Até 2 meses atrás eu podia ficar um tempão programando, agora não dá mais.

Obrigado pelos feedbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Deve-se dar um espaço entre a tabela `Cliente` e o comando `set`:

```
cnxCli.sel =/*"set dateformat dmy \n"+ */
                "update Cliente" +
                 "set Nome = '"
```

Mude para:

```
cnxCli.sel =/*"set dateformat dmy \n"+ */
                "update Cliente " + /*<-----Mudei aqui.*/
                 "set Nome = '"
```

Comment: Agora deu `string or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Qual linha esta informando o erro?

Comment: Geralmente este erro esta relacionado com o tamanho do conteúdo de um campo, veja se vc esta mandando mais dados do que seu campo pode comportar.

Comment: Descobri o erro. Coloquei um breakpoint logo antes de executar a query, veja o que estava dentro do meu select `update Cliente set Nome = 'AAAA',Rg = '11.111.111-1',Cpf ='111.111.111-11',Celular ='System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox, Text: (11) 1 1111-1111',Telefone ='System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox, Text: (11) 1111-1111',DataNascimento = '01/01/1900',Endereco ='AAAA',Bairro='AAAA',Cidade='',Cep ='11111-111',Uf = 'AA',Observacao='aaaa'where IDCliente =1`

Por algum motivo as masked textboxes estão enviando não só o valor, mas este valor estranho. `'System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox`

Comment: No `mskCelular` e no `mskTelefone` coloque a propriedade `Text`. Também sugiro vc seguir as dicas do bigown.