# Cláusula SQL LIKE não funciona com SqlParameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

Seguindo a recomendação que o [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown) fez [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104130/erro-ao-tentar-fazer-update-na-tabela-usando-c) eu resolvi parametrizar as *queries* SQL do meu programa.

Veja:

```
    private void btnConsulta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (optID.Checked) //Consulta por ID
        {
            if (nmrID.Text == "0" || nmrID.Text == "")
                cnxCli.sel = "select * from cliente;";
            else
            {
                cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente " +
                                 "WHERE IDCliente = @ID";

                cnxCli.selCmd.CommandText = cnxCli.sel;
                cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
                cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = nmrID.Text;
            }
            cnxCli.clienteDataTable.Clear();
            cnxCli.clienteAdapter.Fill(cnxCli.clienteDataTable);
            gridPrincipal.Update();

        }
        else if(optNome.Checked)//Consulta por Nome
        {
            if (txtNome.Text == "")
                cnxCli.sel = "select * from cliente";
            else
            {
                cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente " +
                             "WHERE Nome like '%@Nome%'";

                cnxCli.selCmd.CommandText = cnxCli.sel;
                cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.Text);
                cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters["@Nome"].Value = txtNome.Text;
            }
            cnxCli.clienteDataTable.Clear();
            cnxCli.clienteAdapter.Fill(cnxCli.clienteDataTable);
            gridPrincipal.Update();
        }
    }
```

Acontece que a seção de código depois do `else`, que deveria retornar todos os registros contendo o nome relacionado ao parâmetro `@Nome`, retorna apenas uma tabela vazia. Como podem ver a consulta por ID foi feita do mesmo jeito, e ela retorna o resultado do `select` normal.

Fiz uma verificação, setei um *breakpoint* logo após a linha `cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters["@Nome"].Value = txtNome.Text;` para verificar se estava tudo certo.

Verifiquei que `cnxCli.selCmd.CommandText` contém a *string* `"Select * from cliente WHERE Nome like '%@Nome%'"`, como esperado. Imaginei então que algo errado aconteceu com o valor do parâmetro `@Nome`. Porém o valor do parâmetro era o texto encontrado em `txtNome.Text`, também como esperado.

Depois montei a *query* no SQL Server, imaginando que tinha montado o `like '%%'` de forma errado, mas está tudo normal também.

Onde é que estou errando?

***EDIT : SOLUÇÃO ENCONTRADA***

Encontrei um problema similar no Stack Overflow em Inglês.
[Use of SqlParameter in SQL LIKE clause not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665129/use-of-sqlparameter-in-sql-like-clause-not-working)

Por algum motivo que só Deus sabe qual, quando eu faço algo do como `Select * from Cliente WHERE Nome like '@Nome'` ou `Nome like '%@Nome%'`, o que de fato acontece é que o parâmetro não é substituído por seu valor, sendo assim a consulta será executado buscando o nome do parâmetro no banco de dados.

O jeito de se resolver o problema é fazendo isso:

```
cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente " +
             "WHERE Nome like @Nome";//sem aspas ou %%, apenas o nome do parâmetro
```

Depois, deve-se modificar o **valor** do parâmetro quando o atribuímos.

```
cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters["@Nome"].Value = "%"+ txtNome.Text + "%";
```

Eu particularmente achei isso bem esquisito, mas funcionou.

Comment: Parece que está indo no caminho certo para detectar o problema, deve estar faltando algum detalhe. Qual é o texto encontrado em `txtNome.Text`? Olhe no *debugger*, seja se não tem nada estranho ali quando dá o *breakpoint*. Onde está executando a *query*? Não vi em lugar algum. De qualquer forma este trecho omite certas coisas que podem estar erradas. Nem sei se seria ideal usar desta forma, mas não posso falar muito sem ver o resto.

Comment: Vou explorar mais um pouco mais tarde, pois agora minha cabeça já está bem cansada. Mas talvez eu termine resolvendo sozinho o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que o seu problema está no `WHERE`.

Substitua:

```
cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente WHERE Nome like '%@Nome%'";
```

Por:

```
cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente WHERE Nome like @Nome";
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma das maneiras de se resolver:

```
cnxCli.sel = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE Nome LIKE CONCAT('%', @Nome, '%')";
```

Answer (score 3):

Substitua:

```
cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente WHERE Nome like '%@Nome%'";
```

Por:

```
cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente WHERE Nome like '%' + @Nome + '%'";
```

[Referencia 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294954)

[Referencia 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251276/howto-parameters-and-like-statement-sql)

Comment: Você tem que passar a variável assim '%' + @Nome + '%', das outras formas você não terá sucesso.

Answer (score 3):

O `LIKE` deve ser colocado da seguinte forma:

```
cnxCli.sel = "Select * from cliente WHERE Nome like @Nome ";

cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters.Clear();
cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.Text);
cnxCli.selCmd.Parameters["@Nome"].Value = '%' +  txtNome.Text + '%';
```