# Erro ao inserir dados em tabela com coluna do tipo numérico VB NET

Tags: sql-server, query, vb.net

Olá, estou com problemas ao tentar inserir dados em uma banco SQL através do VB.NET.

Estou migrando alguns projetos vb6 para .net, me deparei com o primeiro problema o qual passei o dia tentando resolver sem sucesso.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Abastecimento (Data, Data_abast, hora, prefixo, bomba, Combustivel) VALUES ('" & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & "','" & Trim(TextBox2.Text) & "','" &
                                    dd & "','" & Trim(TextBox5.Text) & "','" & Trim(CInt(TextBox12.Text)) & "','" & v_combustivel & "')"
```

Ao tentar fazer esse INSERT, recebo o erro:

> Error converting data type

Verifiquei que ao tirar a coluna Combustivel o query funciona, ou seja algo de errado ao tentar inserir nessa coluna.

Obs:
1 - A coluna  Combustivel esta como numeric(4, 1) no sql server
2 - O valor que estou tentando passar através da váriavel v_combustivel é 150,5; já tentei substituir virgula por ponto etc.

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço :D

Comment: Deve ser isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104130/101 E isto pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293843/101, portanto o jeito que está fazendo está completamente equivocado.

Comment: Já experimentou imprimir para consola ou para `MessageBox` o resultado da variável `sql`? Após colocar esse resultado diretamente no SQL de certeza que já percebia qual o problema. Mas como o @Maniero referiu, não é a forma mais correta de se fazer.

Comment: INSERT INTO Abastecimento(Data, Data_abast, hora, prefixo, bomba, Combustivel) VALUES ('2019/10/08','2019/10/0/','0:30:38','000431','1','25,1')


Obs:"Combustivel esta na tabela SQL como numeric(4, 1)"

Sou iniciante, talvez seja algo simples, mas ainda não consegui identificar a causa do problema.

Eu fazia da mesma forma no VB6 com cdbl() funcionava bem. :/

Obs:Em relação em ser a forma correta de fazer por questões de segurança etc, estou estudando ainda então muita coisa ai foi na base de tentativa e erro.

Obrigado !

Comment: Solução:
Ao invés de juntar dois textbox em uma variável, solicitei o valor inteiro apenas em uma váriavel, no caso o textbox1, fiz um replace() para substituir a virgula por ponto e funcionou bem.

sql = "INSERT INTO Abastecimento (Data, Data_abast, hora, prefixo, bomba, Combustivel) VALUES ('" & Trim(data_SQL(TextBox1.Text)) & "','" & Trim(data_SQL(TextBox2.Text)) & "','" &
         dd & "','" & Trim(TextBox5.Text) & "','" & Trim(CInt(TextBox12.Text)) & "'," & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & ")"